# Stuck in login loop after AMD gpu pro driver install

Tags: login, amdgpu-pro

After I installed AMD GPU-pro driver, I am not able to login to my account. The OS boots to the user login screen (without showing the ubuntu splash screen) and after I enter my password and hit enter, the login screen appears again like it just booted up.

Please help with the issue. I would not mind reinstalling the OS if that is the only work around (dual booting with windows 10)

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to run (16.04 LTS or a newer or older version)?

Comment: I think you should *avoid* proprietary AMD drivers with 16.04 LTS and newer versions. Instead, the free linux drivers should work well. -- Try to remove the proprietary AMD driver. If that does not work, you can reinstall Ubuntu (the same version, 16.04 LTS is the newest version with long time support).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I manage to fix my problem by installing the px and compute packages for amdgpu-pro

From the installation folder, run:

```
amdgpu-pro-install --px
```

You will be prompted for confirmation twice -- once to uninstall, and once to install. Then reboot.

OLD (semi-)answer:

It looks like the screen is running from the Intel graphics card (i915). Does your laptop have switchable graphics ?

As a temporary fix, you can try running a window manager without a compositor -- I've found that Xmonad works fine in my setup. Though anything 3D-accellerated will not work.

I am facing a similar problem (same symptoms) on my laptop, which has Intel graphics. It seems the packages installed by amdgpu-pro are incompatible with the non-AMD drivers included in Ubuntu, looking for this `is64bitelf`symbol.

Comment: I have installed 16.04 and I have hybrid graphics.